# Generate only a Lexer from Antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am attempting to use Antlr to tokenize and classify the tokens of an input stream.  Does anyone know of a way to generate only a Lexer from Antlr using a grammar with only Lexer rules?

Comment: Did you get a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the type of grammar you want using the grammar title line.

```
grammar MyGrammar;
```

for combined grammars.

```
lexer grammar MyLexer;
```

for a lexer grammar (etc.). Of course in a pure lexer grammar you may only use lexer rules.

Comment: Is it possible to generate only a lexer from a lexer grammar? Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely! Specify only the lexer grammar in your call to the antlr4 tool and it will only create lexer target files for you.

Comment: Thanks. `antlr4 CommonLexerRules.g4` generates `CommonLexerRules.java` (not `CommonLexerRulesLexer.java`). After `javac CommonLexerRules.java`, I run `grun CommonLexerRules startRuleName='tokens' -tokens`. However, it produces an error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CommonLexerRulesParser`.

Comment: I got it: it should be `grun CommonLexerRules tokens -tokens`.

Answer (score -1):

You can basically generate a parser and extend the listener class then inside every exitMethod() push the tokens into a stack.

You can't generate only a lexer. If you are not familiar with ANTLR 4 grammar or the steps required to generate a parser, I advise you to spend 10 mins in reading this book "The definitive of ANTLR 4".